# Moq - Mock DbSet<T>.AddAsync throws no invocations performed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, ef-core-2.2

I have a unit test that is basically testing the behaviour of EF Core. The class I am trying to test looks like this:

```cs
namespace MusicPortal.Repository.Repository
{
    public class ArtistRepository : IArtistRepository
    {
        private readonly MusicPortalDbContext _context;

        public ArtistRepository(MusicPortalDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<MusicPortalDatabaseResponse<bool>> AddNewArtist(Artist artist)
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.Artists.AddAsync(new Artist
                {
                    ArtistType = ArtistTypes.Band,
                    City = artist.City,
                    Country = artist.Country,
                    Genre = artist.Genre,
                    Name = artist.Name,
                    ProfileImageUrl = artist.ProfileImageUrl
                });

                _context.SaveChanges();
                return new MusicPortalDatabaseResponse<bool>
                {
                    HasError = false,
                    Exception = null,
                    Response = true
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new MusicPortalDatabaseResponse<bool>
                {
                    HasError = true,
                    Exception = e,
                    Response = false
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following Unit Test for it using Moq

```cs
namespace MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.AddNewArtist
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GivenAddingANewArtistToADatabaseFails
    {
        private Mock<DbSet<Artist>> _mockArtistDbSet;
        private Mock<MusicPortalDbContext> _mockContext;

        private IArtistRepository _artistRepository;
        private MusicPortalDatabaseResponse<bool> _addArtistToDbResponse;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public async Task Setup()
        {
            _mockArtistDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Artist>>();
            _mockContext = new Mock<MusicPortalDbContext>();

            _mockArtistDbSet
                .Setup(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Artist>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .Callback((Artist artist, CancellationToken token) => { })
                .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<EntityEntry<Artist>>());
            _mockContext
                .Setup(x => x.SaveChanges())
                .Throws(new Exception("Cannot save new Artist to Database"));

            _artistRepository = new MusicPortal.Repository.Repository.ArtistRepository(_mockContext.Object);
            _addArtistToDbResponse = await _artistRepository.AddNewArtist(It.IsAny<Artist>());
        }

        [Test]
        public void ThenANegativeResultIsReturned() // pass
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(_addArtistToDbResponse.Response);
            Assert.IsTrue(_addArtistToDbResponse.HasError);
            Assert.IsInstanceOf<Exception>(_addArtistToDbResponse.Exception);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ThenTheArtistContextAddMethodIsCalledOnce() //fail
        {
            _mockArtistDbSet.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Artist>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ThenTheArtistsContextSaveMethodIsNeverCalled() //pass
        {
            _mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Never);
        }
    }
}
```

The first and last assertion pass but `ThenTheArtistContextAddMethodIsCalledOnce()` fails due to the following error:

> MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.AddNewArtist.GivenAddingANewArtistToADatabaseFails.ThenTheArtistContextAddMethodIsCalledOnce
>
> Moq.MockException : 
>   Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())
>
> Performed invocations:
>
> Mock:1> (x):
>      No invocations performed.
>
> at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
>      at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)
>      at MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.AddNewArtist.GivenAddingANewArtistToADatabaseFails.ThenTheArtistContextAddMethodIsCalledOnce() in MusicPortal.Tests\Repository\ArtistRepository\AddNewArtist\GivenAddingANewArtistToADatabaseFails.cs:line 53

I'm understanding that the problem code is `c#
 _mockArtistDbSet
                .Setup(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Artist>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .Callback((Artist artist, CancellationToken token) => { })
                .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<EntityEntry<Artist>>());`

And I know the problem is most likely due to async issue but I don't know why, or what the actual problem is. Any advice, solutions?

Comment: Shouldn't your last test also fail? It looks like SaveChanges should be called.

Comment: That setup code shouldn't really be there but no, the Save method would never be called because the code for adding to the dbSet throws an error and would defer to the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like EF Core is not so easily tested with async tasks such as `SaveChangesAsync` and `AddAsync`. In the end, I followed the MS guide for testing EF core and created a mock context. The only downside being I can only test happy path. Although error paths are tested by the service which consumes the repository, I was hoping for more test coverage on the repository layer.

Anyway, here's the spec

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MusicPortal.Core.Context;
using MusicPortal.Core.Repository;
using MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.TestHelpers;
using MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.TestHelpers.MockDB;
using NUnit.Framework;
using MockArtistRepository = MusicPortal.Repository.Repository.ArtistRepository;

namespace MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.AddNewArtist 
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GivenANewArtistToInsertIntoTheDb
    {
        private DbContextOptions<MusicPortalDbContext> _options;
        private MusicPortalDatabaseResponse<bool> _mockResponse;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public async Task Setup()
        {
            _options = new MockDbFactory("MusicPortalDB").Options;

            using (var context = new MusicPortalDbContext(_options))
            {
                var artistRepository = new MockArtistRepository(context);
                _mockResponse = await artistRepository.AddNewArtist(MockRepositoryData.Artist);
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void AndThenAPositiveResultIsReturned()
        {
            Assert.Null(_mockResponse.Exception);
            Assert.IsTrue(_mockResponse.Response);
            Assert.IsFalse(_mockResponse.HasError);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ThenTheArtistShouldBeSavedWithNoProblem()
        {
            using (var context = new MusicPortalDbContext(_options))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(1, context.Artists.Count());
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

and the Mock Database:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MusicPortal.Core.Context;
using MusicPortal.Core.DBModels;

namespace MusicPortal.Tests.Repository.ArtistRepository.TestHelpers.MockDB
{
    public sealed class MockDbFactory
    {
        public DbContextOptions<MusicPortalDbContext> Options { get; }

        public MockDbFactory(string dbName)
        {
            Options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MusicPortalDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName)
                .Options;
        }

        public void AddArtistsToContext()
        {
            using (var context = new MusicPortalDbContext(Options))
            {
                context.Artists.Add(new Artist
                {
                    City = "Orange County",
                    Country = "USA",
                    Events = null,
                    Genre = "Pop Punk",
                    Id = Guid.Parse("8a07504b-8152-4d8b-8e21-74bf64322ebc"),
                    Merchandise = null,
                    Name = "A Day To Remember",
                    ArtistType = "Band",
                    ProfileImageUrl = "https://placehold.it/30x30"
                });

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone looking at the same issue. The lesson learned is don't use Async unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

You declare and setup _mockArtistDbSet, but you don't use/attach it to the _mockContext.  I think you need to add something like:

```
_mockContext.Setup(m => m.Artist).Returns(_mockArtistDbSet.Object);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same issue. I'm thinking of just refactoring to make blocking calls to the DB. Might take a performance hit on some of my services but I'd rather have testable code than no coverage on my repositories